# How to know if a contact is Facetime user or iPhone user in the Addressbook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook, facetime

I am programing with the Address Book, I want to find out the Facetime/iPhone user in the Contacts List. I found there is a "Facetime" item in some contact details. I have checked the  framework already. but only found a property call "kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel", how to judge if contact is Facetime user? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this questions? :)

Comment: @Will  Not yet. My app had given up this feature.